# Sum until specific criterion is met

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was looking for a formula which will stop the SUM operation as soon as it finds the value in the column.

```
Total   Pass    Fail
36  35  1
58  57  1
32  34  1
59  58  1
42  41  1
77  75  2
44  44  0
53  52  1
57  55  2
52  50  2
54  53  1
49  48  1
```

Here the summation will stop when in Fail column will finds 0 like the orange marked regardless of the values afterward. Here the Total sum will be 7 instead of 14 because of the 0.

Comment: While there's no proper answer, find "excel lookup last value in column" videos on YouTube, might help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C12,--(ROW(C2:C12)<MATCH(0,C2:C12,0)+1))
```

or (per Scott Craner's suggestion)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C12,--(ROW(C2:C12)<MATCH(0,C:C,0)))
```

This will sum all cells in `C2:C12` whose row is smaller than the row of the first cell with a `0`

Comment: The match should be: `MATCH(0,C:C,0)` otherwise the row will be off by 1.

Comment: @Scott Craner - See my edit. I had the `+1` to account for the row offset, unless it introduces a problem I didn't foresee?

Comment: I did not see that.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad,, second formula is working properly but not the first one, returns `0`!

Comment: @Rajesh S - both work fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM($C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(0,C:C,0)))
```

Similar to SUMPRODUCT given above, but avoids the use of array calculations  It assumes row 1 is a header row and the data starts in row 2.  The match does the same job, it finds the location of the first 0 in column C:C.  INDEX returns the cell address of that location.

[image: POC]